# Create over 3 million topics in Fcm

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently in the process of integrating Firebase's Cloud Messaging feature into a project, and I need to create over 3 million notification topics. Is this feasible, or will I encounter any system limitations?

Is there a limitation on the number of topics I can have in one FCM project?
In my app, I expect that a user will subscribe to fewer than 20 topics.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of [documented limitations for FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options), but number of topics isn't listed among them. The documented limits have more to do with [throttling and scaling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#throttling-and-scaling).

If you do have problems, you might want to reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for troubleshooting.